# Example $\mathrm{ord}(x)$ finite, $\mathrm{ord}(y)$ finite and $\mathrm{ord}(xy)$ infinite

Tags: group-theory

Another post had quite a similar question [Example of a group with elements $a,b$
such that $\mathrm{ord}(a)=\mathrm{ord}(b)=\mathrm{ord}(ab)=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455814/example-of-a-group-with-elements-a-b-such-that-mboxorda-mboxordb?rq=1).

So my question is there is any simple example that can be made for an arbitrary group $G$ and elements $x,y \in G$ such that:

$\mathrm{ord}(x) < \infty $, $\mathrm{ord}(y) < \infty$ and $\mathrm{ord}(xy)$ infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider two finite cyclic $G$, $H$ group generated by $x$ and $y$ and consider the free product $G*H$, $ord$(x*y)$ is infinite.

See the answer here

[Free products of cyclic groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91626/free-products-of-cyclic-groups)

Answer (score 0):

If you take the nontrivial semidirect product $\mathbb Z \rtimes (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$, then the composition rule is $(a,0) \bullet (b,c) = (a+b,c)$ while $(a,1) \bullet (b,c) = (a-b,1+c)$.

As a result, if you take $x = (a,1)$ and $y = (b,1)$ for any $a$ and $b$ with $a+b \ne 0$, then $x \bullet x = y \bullet y = (0,0)$, so $x$ and $y$ have order $2$, but $x \bullet y = (a-b,0)$ has infinite order.